# Lambda inside Lambda

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lambda

assume we have a lambda expression like

```
        var thread= new Thread(() =>
        {
            Foo1();
            Foo2(() =>
            {
                Foo3();
                DoSomething();
            }
            );
        });
```

the question is when `DoSomething()` evaluated? on `thread` creation or on calling `thread.Start()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DoSomething()` may *never* be called. It will only be called if `Foo2()` executes the delegate it's given. So the order of execution is:

1. Delegate is created and passed to the `Thread` constructor. None of the code in the delegate is executed.
2. Presumably someone calls `thread.Start()`.
3. `Foo1()` executes
4. A delegate is created (or possibly retrieved from a cached field) representing the calls to `Foo3()` and `DoSomething()`, but those calls are not executed yet
5. The delegate reference is passed to `Foo2()`
6. If `Foo2()` executes the delegate, *then* `Foo3()` and `DoSomething()` will be executed

Comment: Of course Foo2() could also assign the delegate to a variable, and another function much later (and possibly on another thread, or even the original thread) could end up executing it, potentially numerous times. Its a

Answer (score 0):

The delegate could be called never or multiple times. Foo2() could do anything it wants with the delegate including assigning it to a variable somewhere or ignoring it altogether.

We only know that if run it must happen at some point after the thread has started and Foo1() has executed without throwing an uncaught exception.